# change default window of ckfinder3 that integrated with ckeditor5 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, ckfinder3

> **in shortcut:**  `filebrowserBrowseUrl` is not working or missing in `ckeditor5` and `ckfinder3`

**in details** :

I am trying to add `ckfinder3` to the editor `ckeditor5` with `Laravel project`, and I have already done that and everything is fine.

> **my full code of import and integrate ckeditor5 and ckfinder3**

```
ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
            ckfinder: {
        
        },
extraPlugins: [ MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ],
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        'link',
                        'alignment',
                        'fontSize',
                        'fontColor',
                        'fontBackgroundColor',
                        'fontFamily',
                        'CKFinder',
                        'imageUpload',
                        'bulletedList',
                        'numberedList',
                        'insertTable',
                        'highlight',
                        '|',
                        'indent',
                        'outdent',
                        '|',
                        'exportPdf',
                        'codeBlock',
                        'blockQuote',
                        'mediaEmbed',
                        'undo',
                        'redo',
                        'code'
                    ]
                },
                language: 'en',
                image: {
                    toolbar: [
                        'imageTextAlternative',
                        'imageStyle:full',
                        'imageStyle:side'
                    ]
                },
                table: {
                    contentToolbar: [
                        'tableColumn',
                        'tableRow',
                        'mergeTableCells'
                    ]
                },
                licenseKey: '',

            } )
            .then( editor => {
                window.editor = editor;




            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( 'Oops, something gone wrong!' );
                console.error( 'Please, report the following error in the https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5 with the build id and the error stack trace:' );
                console.warn( 'Build id: swaslk6qkuya-fnxcjcmhlf3i' );
                console.error( error );
            } );
```

But I am faced with a problem which is when I try to open a window to browse files that opens to a **strange** window I think is "external" or on the `official ckeditor server` (demo window).look
[image]
**Note** this window appears only when i use `CKFINDER` with `CKEDITOR` because i downloaded `CKFINDER` as a manual and downloaded the `browse.blade.php` file and I made a route to access the file and it works locally without any problem.

```
Route::get('ckfinder', function () {
   return view('ckfinder::browser');
});
```

so how to link this page to `browse.blade.php` with the `ckeditor` editor?